# Error EADDRNOTAVAIL with Heroku nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have developped a nodejs server on OpenShift and I am now trying to make the same kind of server on Heroku for a new project.

Here is a minimal code of my server:

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var address = process.env.IP || '127.0.0.1';

console.log(address);
console.log(port);

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res)
{
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
    res.write(JSON.stringify({ valid: true }));
    res.end();
});

server.listen(port, address);
```

Differences with my OpenShift server are:

- The replacement of variables process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT, process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP by process.env.PORT and process.env.IP.
- I set the IP variable with this command line: heroku config:set IP=MYSERVERADDRESS.com

I cannot start my server, it always crash and I don't understand why, the logs of my server are:

```
MYSERVERADDRESS.com
41184
events.js:154
       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
   ^
 Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL MYSERVERIP:41184
     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)
     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:916:20)
     at Server.__dirname.Server.Server._listen2 (net.js:1233:19)
     at net.js:1391:9
     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:63:16)
     at listen (net.js:1282:10)
     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:82:10)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess would be that your Heroku server will not have your (external) server address as its (internal) IP-number (the external IP-address will most likely terminate earlier in the Heroku network stack), which means that you cannot explicitly listen on it (which is basically what `EADDRNOTAVAIL` means).

Instead, don't use an address to listen to at all:

```
server.listen(port);
```

Comment: For any `feathers.js` folks having the same issue. This worked for me.